# the way to get cache placement policy of cpu on Linux

Tags: cpu-cache

cache placement policy :

inclusive / exclusive / no-inclusive no-exclusive

where can get the cache placement policy on Linux os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache allocation policy is a property of the architecture.
Most often than not, this is not a configurable property and it is not exposed to the OS but within the Reference Manuals of the specific architecture.

If you want to know the cache allocation property of your CPU you need to read its manuals.

If you have a recent Intel CPU then the L2 is Non-Inclusive/Non-Exclusive and the L3 is either inclusive (mostly for workstation CPUs) or Non-Inclusive/Non-Exclusive (for server CPUs since SkylakeX, especially those with many cores).